# App/Library implementing PayPoint's 3rd generation PSP (a.k.a Advanced Payments)

Tags: library, php, online-payment, sdk

I'm looking for an PHP OOP app or library which implements PayPoint's 3rd generation PSP as documented in this [Developer Documentation](https://developer.paypoint.com/payments/docs/#getting_started/getting_started) (supporting both MITE and LIVE Endpoints).

So far I've found:

- [iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypoint/mobilesdk-ios) (see: [API references](http://paypoint.github.io/headerdoc/mobilesdk-ios/));
- [Android SDK](https://github.com/paypoint/mobilesdk-android) (see: [API references](http://paypoint.github.io/javadocs/mobilesdk-android/));
- API client in Ruby ([PayPoint::Blue](https://github.com/CPlus/paypoint-blue))

so obviously not PHP.

The only PHP which I've found, is Drupal module: [Commerce Paypoint](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypoint) (which includes [Gateway Hosted](https://www.paypoint.net/assets/guides/Gateway_Hosted.pdf) & [Gateway Freedom](https://www.paypoint.net/assets/guides/Gateway_Freedom.pdf) integration, so it's completely different API with different endpoints);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote a [class](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_paypoint/tree/advanced_payments/commerce_paypoint_advanced.class.inc) as part of the Drupal module. See project [home page](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypoint), [main repository](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_paypoint) and mirror on [GitHub](https://github.com/kenorb-contrib/commerce_paypoint).

Sample usage (PHP, code Drupal 7 oriented):

```
  $ppo = new PPOAdvancedPayment($url, $username, $password, $instId, $hosted);
  $ppo->setSessionReturnUrl($returnUrl);
  $ppo->setSessionNotificationUrl($notifyUrl);
  $ppo->setCustomerDetails($billing_address['name_line'], $address, $telephone, $email, $ip_address);
  $ppo->setTransactionMerchantReference('your_reference_here');
  $ppo->setTransactionMoneyFixed($total['amount'], $total['currency_code']);
  $ppo->setCustomerNew();
  $ppo->setCustomerMerchantId('1111111111112');
  $response = array();
  try {
    $response = $ppo->sendProcessPayment();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    watchdog_exception('commerce_paypoint_advanced', $e);
  }
  $response = $ppo->getLastResponse();
  $status = $ppo->getLastStatus();
  $code = $ppo->getLastCode();
  $data = $ppo->getLastData();
  if ($settings['connectivity']['debug'] || variable_get('commerce_paypoint_debug', FALSE)) {
    watchdog('commerce_paypoint_advanced', 'PayPoint response:\n<br>%data', array('%data' => json_encode($ppo->getLastResponse())), WATCHDOG_DEBUG);
  }
```